# Magento2 : Set Product limit in Related and Upsell Product

Tags: magento2, product-view

Hi Everyone i want to set Product Limit in Related and Upsell Product in View page Magento 2.

Any one have idea to set limit.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the layout if you don't want to create a plugin.

***Assuming you have a theme "Vendor_default" and running Magento >= 2.1.2***

**Upsell Products**:

- Create the file app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell">
            <action method="setItemLimit">
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">5</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

**Related Products**:

- Copy/paste `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`
- In `case 'related'` block, Change $limit. (ie: `$limit = 0` into `$limit = 4`)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the **plugin** system of Magento 2.

The objective of plugin is to add a limit on the product items without overriding the module `Magento_Catalog` itself with an **after plugin**.

This is an example for the **Related Product List** :

1. Assume that you have an existing module `Vendor_Module`
2. Create `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` file and this block of code :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related">
           <plugin name="vendor_module_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Related" sortOrder="0" />
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
3. Create `Vendor/Module/Block/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Related.php` and add this code in :

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

   /**
    * Class Related
    *
    * @package Vendor\Module\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList
    */
   class Related
   {
       /**
        * Add limit to related product collection if page_size argument is defined
        *
        * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $subject
        * @param $result
        *
        * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
        */
       public function afterGetItems(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $subject, $result)
       {
           $pageSize = 10;
           $collection = $result;

           if ($pageSize) {
               $collection->getSelect()->limit($pageSize);
           }

           return $collection;
       }
   }
   ```

You can do the same thing for Upsell product :).

Comment: I tried this but not working.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example for the **Upsell Product List :**

Create the file app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml

Line No. 62 replace below code:

```
$limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
```

to

```
$limit = 3;
```

and 
Line No. 82 replace below code:

```
 $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
```

to

```
$limit = 3;
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. Is this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is working solution now and its better for performance because it limits the related products before database load.

1.Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module::plugin_product" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="0"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Create plugin class

   ```
   <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product;

    /**
     * Class ProductPlugin
     *
     * @package Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product
     */
    class ProductPlugin
    {
        public function afterGetRelatedProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
        {
            $pageSize = 6;
            $collection = $result;

            if ($pageSize) {
                $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
            }

            return $collection;
        }
    }
   ```