# How can I increase the number of related products shown on product detail page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, xml, products, related-products

I am running Magento 2.3.3 and currently show 4 products on the product detail page. Where do I go to increase that number to 6? I have found nothing in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Related Products:**

**Copy/paste**

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

to

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

In `case 'related'` block, Change **$limit**. (ie: `$limit = 0 into $limit = 6`)

And Read this link for more information:-

**[Magento2 : Set Product limit in Related and Upsell Product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124826/magento2-set-product-limit-in-related-and-upsell-product)**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...